# Does manipulation of a sub-doman to a different domain name cause any issues with an SSL wildcard?

Tags: domains, https, subdomain, security-certificate

For example, if I have a subdomain of:

```
https://foobar.somesite.com
```

that is hosting the site but I want to pass the actual domain of:

```
https://foobar.com
```

in the browser would this cause any issues when using a wildcard SSL certaficate on anything for:

```
*.somesite.com
```

When I research how to do it properly my understanding is I should pass a 301 redirect on `foobar` to `somesite` then use something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(*)$ http://a.example.com/$1
  ...
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

If there is another way to do this please let me know but I have to use a SSL on the sub-domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSL certificate for `*.somesite.com` will not match `somesite.com` so you will get SSL errors when you try to connect to your site if you use this certificate. You will need to get another certificate or be able to add `somesite.com` as a Subject Alternative Name of your certificate for `*.somesite.com`